# Transform local software into online software

Tags: java, database, architecture, client-server, synchronization

We've developed a management software specifically to very small businesses. But, unexpectedly, several bigger businesses liked it and started to use it. The problem is that our software works only locally (one store) and the bigger businesses want us to make the software to work online (two or more stores at different places but with the same database).

So, we would like to make our local software to work online, utilizing our already existent JAVA Swing user interface.

We've thought about some solutions but,  as it will be a big change, we would like to know what is the best way to proceed.

**Important information:**

- The user interface is JAVA Swing and the database is Postgresql.
- We have thousands of customers using our software and they would like to use it online too.

Below are the solutions that we've thought about. Please, let us know if there is a better way.

**Solution #1**

A single database in internet and all clients connected to it.

Drawbacks:

1. Every single query would have to access internet.
2. The source code of the clients would need to have the database password. Then the security would be totally compromised.

**Solution #2**

All clients would have their own database in internet, with different passwords.

Drawbacks:

1. Every single query would have to access internet.
2. Would need thousand of databases.
3. Difficult to maintain.

**Solution #3**

A single database in internet, but clients connecting through a web service that validates the customers login data and returns the queries results.

Drawbacks:

1. Every single query would have to access internet.
2. The construction of the web service would be a little complex and it would have to return the results in somehow we don't know (maybe simple csv text or xml).

**Solution #4**

[image]

There would exist a single database in the internet for all our customers.

Also, all the clients would have their own database locally, so they could do fast select queries.

Every update query would be firstly sent to a web service that would execute the query at the online database and return if it were successfully done.

Besides that, we would have a mechanism to synchronize the local databases with the online database from time to time.

Drawbacks:

1. Very complex and difficult to implement.
2. The synchronize mechanism would require high processing.

**Is there a better way? How?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with Solution #3. Build a database-backed service/API, and have the desktop client authenticate itself and use it. I would avoid having a local database as in Solution #4. You cannot rely on your users not to accidentally mess with it somehow and cause synchronization to be lost or corrupted. In addition, having a local database will slow you down when you want to create a different client, for example a mobile app.

If you decide to go with Solution #3, the current de facto standard is JSON-based REST API. Also, you should note that there are many caching techniques that can be used which will reduce the number of queries actually run.

Comment: Thank you for the opinion, Khalid. I would like to know more about the cashing techniques. What are the ones that you suggest us to use?

Comment: There are many. There is local cache, API cache, database cache, etc. It depends on the stack used and the specific requirements.